# script for DNS Resolver

Tags: bash

How could make bash script to filter list of DNS resolver
because it out with false positive results

suggested code

```
!/bin/sh
for IP in `cat ./resolvers.txt`; do
    printf "%-4s", $IP
    dig @$IP test.com
done
```

test.com is my domain which I already know what the output would be, then any different result would be from bad resolver.

Comment: Why tag "python"?

Comment: See [Why you don't read lines with `for`](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor)

Comment: @GenoChen because it could be made in python BUT i don`t have experience in python programming

Comment: @Emad, tag only for topics your question is actually *about*, not for tools you merely speculate might be used.

Comment: @Emad Then it has nothing to do at this question. I removed it.

Comment: The shebang needs to start with exactly the two characters `#!`. Putting `sh` makes this a Bourne [tag:sh] script, not a [tag:bash] script. See also [Difference between sh and bash](/questions/5725296/difference-between-sh-and-bash).

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
case $BASH_VERSION in '') echo "ERROR: Use bash, not sh" >&2; exit 1;; esac

test_domain="test.com"
correct_ip=1.2.3.4

while IFS= read -r ip; do
  if [[ $(dig +short "@$ip" "$test_domain" 2>/dev/null) = "$correct_ip" ]]; then
    printf '%s\n' "$ip"
  fi
done <all-resolvers.txt >good-resolvers.txt
```

...will read `all-resolvers.txt`, and write a list of only the DNS servers that correctly function (resolve `test_domain` to `correct_ip`) to `good-resolvers.txt`.

---

See:

- [BashFAQ #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) - Best practices for reading an input file in bash line-by-line
- [the conditional expression](https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/ccmd/conditional_expression), aka `[[ ]]`, on the bash-hackers' wiki.